# WP All Export for Wordpress: How can I get XML output by separating a variant product according to its attributes?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

Below is the XML file that I actively use.
But I have no idea how to enter separate stock, price, sku numbers for products with variants.
How can I solve this problem?

My XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Urunler>
    <!-- BEGIN LOOP -->
    <urun>
        <StokKodu>{ID}</StokKodu>
        <Barkod>{Sku}</Barkod>
        <Marka>{MARKA ürün}</Marka>
        <Kategori>{Ürün kategorileri}</Kategori>
        <Desi>{Weight}</Desi>
        <Baslik>{Title}</Baslik>
        <KisaTanim>{Excerpt}</KisaTanim>
        <Stok>{Stock}</Stok>
        <Fiyat>{Price}</Fiyat>
        <Aciklama>{Content}</Aciklama>
        <Resimler><Resim>{Image URL}</Resim></Resimler>
        <Extended_Xml_Attributes>
            <variants>
                <variant>
                    <Stock>{Stock}</Stock>
                    <Price>{Price}</Price>
                    <Barkod>{Sku}</Barkod>
                    <Beden>{BEDEN ürün}</Beden>
                </variant>
            </variants>
        </Extended_Xml_Attributes>
    </urun>
    <!-- END LOOP -->
</Urunler>
```

What I want to do is similar to this.
I am using wp all Export Customize Xml Feed

```
<Product>
    <SKU>10027105</SKU>
    <Brand_Name>Adidas</Brand_Name>
    <Product_Name>Adidas Mens Climacool Boat Lace Shoes - Sale</Product_Name>
    <Long_Description>...</Long_Description>
    <Short_Description>...</Short_Description>
    <Category>Footwear</Category>
    <SubCategory>Casual</SubCategory>
    <Product_Group>Men's</Product_Group>
    <Thumb_URL>...</Thumb_URL>
    <Image_URL>...</Image_URL>
    <Buy_Link>...</Buy_Link>
    <Retail_Price>74.99</Retail_Price>
    <Sale_Price>59.99</Sale_Price>
    <Extended_Xml_Attributes>
        <variants>
            <variant>
                <sku>19301</sku>
                <upc>0886833708180</upc>
                <size>8</size>
                <color>Dark Indigo</color>
                <retail_price>74.99</retail_price>
                <sale_price>59.99</sale_price>
                <action_url>...</action_url>
            </variant>
            <variant/>
            ...
        </variants>
    </Extended_Xml_Attributes>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML Editor: [deneme({ID})]

```
<?php
    function deneme($id){
    
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
    
        $children = $product->get_children();
    
        $xml = '';
            
        if( !empty( $children ) ){
    
            $var_array = array();
    
            $xml .= '<Varyantlar>';
    
            foreach( $children as $variation ){
    
                $single_variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation);
    
                $var = $single_variation->get_variation_attributes();
    
                if( !empty( $var ) ){
    
                    $xml .= '<Varyant>';
                    //$xml .= '<VaryantGrupID>'.$id.'</VaryantGrupID>';
                    $xml .= '<StokKodu>'.$variation.'</StokKodu>';
                    //$xml .= '<Name>'.$single_variation->get_name().'</Name>';
                    $xml .= '<Barkod>'.$single_variation->get_sku().'</Barkod>';
                    $xml .= '<Beden>'.$single_variation->get_attribute( 'beden' ).'</Beden>';
                    //$xml .= '<Description>'. $single_variation->get_description() .'</Description>';
                    $xml .= '<Stok>'.$single_variation->get_stock_quantity().'</Stok>';
                    $xml .= '<Fiyat>'.$single_variation->get_price().'</Fiyat>';
                    
                    
                    $xml .= '</Varyant>';
                }
    
            }
    
            $xml .= '</Varyantlar>';
    
        }
    
        return $xml;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).